# Unable to handle linspace properly

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I tried the following code to plot a graph

```
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

R=input('enter the rate of rainfall in mm/hr ')


D=np.linspace(0.2,6,30)


n=0.08

l=41*pow(R,(-0.21))

N=n*exp(-l*D)

plt.plot(D,N)
```

I wanted starting point in X axis as 0.2 and endpoint as 6.0, with 0.5 interval but what I'm getting is starting point 0 endpoint 6 interval 1!

Can anyone please tell me where I'm making the mistake? 
Thanks

Comment: It's not clear what `starting point 0 endpoint 6 interval 1` means. Maybe including an image and explaining what exactly you would like to change would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are confusing a few things here:

First, `np.linspace(0.2,6,30)` actually gives a spacing of 0.2:

```
np.linspace(0.2,6,30) 
array([ 0.2,  0.4,  0.6,  0.8,  1. ,  1.2,  1.4,  1.6,  1.8,  2. ,  2.2,
    2.4,  2.6,  2.8,  3. ,  3.2,  3.4,  3.6,  3.8,  4. ,  4.2,  4.4,
    4.6,  4.8,  5. ,  5.2,  5.4,  5.6,  5.8,  6. ])
```

If you want values between 0.2 and 6 with 0.5 spacing, you need to use `np.arange`:

```
np.arange(0.2,6,0.5)
array([ 0.2,  0.7,  1.2,  1.7,  2.2,  2.7,  3.2,  3.7,  4.2,  4.7,  5.2,
    5.7])
```

But when you say you get "starting point 0 endpoint 6 interval 1!", I think you are actually referring to the limits of the X axis on the plot? Your code currently produces this graph:
[image: your code]

You can change the X axis limits to be between 0.2 and 6 by adding `plt.xlim(0.2,6)` to your code. However, your labels will still be from 0 to 6. We can explicitly force them to be the way you want:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

R=input('enter the rate of rainfall in mm/hr ')  
#D=np.linspace(0.2,6,30)
D = np.arange(0.2,6,0.5)  

n=0.08
l=41*pow(R,(-0.21))
N=n*np.exp(-l*D)

plt.plot(D,N)
plt.xlim(0.2,6)
plt.gca().set_xticks(D) # This

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, I just started using ipython and it's awesome!

Comment: Not a problem. If you're happy with my answer, would you mind accepting it (press the tick next to it)? Good luck learning!

Answer (score 0):

See np.arange to set the parameters of your axis.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# evenly sampled time at 200ms intervals
t = np.arange(0., 5., 0.2)
```

http://matplotlib.org/users/pyplot_tutorial.html